# How can i add a click on a dropdown to capture the clicked event?

Tags: reactjs

I am calling a Dropdown Component from controller and i want to add a click to capture an event in controller. How can i add a click? Code below:

```
 <Dropdown label="Select Client"
           name="select Client"
           options={dropdownOptions}
 />
```

Comment: Although I don’t see a duplicate question, there are many other StackOverflow questions asking about click handlers in ReactJS (you’ll see how to bind/capture the event in the examples). Then there is the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-pass-an-event-handler-like-onclick-to-a-component), not sure if you’ve checked it yet.

Comment: I have tried it with something like this but not a success: <Dropdown label="Select Client"
                                name="select Client"
                                options={dropdownOptions}
                                onClick={() => this.handleClick}
                    />

Comment: That’d be good information to add to the question.

Comment: How can i add an event ? Someone can help me with this?

Comment: I detailed an answer for your situation. See below for the example and reference to the documentation.

Mostly, you don't use onclick events on the component. Instead you treat event handlers like regular html using DOM event handlers but instead you're doing it in react's variation in jsx.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you would like to add an event onto your component "Dropdown", and in the comments, you mention you have tried the following:

```
<Dropdown label="Select Client"
name="select Client"
options={dropdownOptions}
onClick={() => this.handleClick} />
```

This isn't the correct way to handle events. Events such as onclick will remain as part of your standard jsx. So instead of putting onclick on the component "Dropdown" itself, you'll return it in JSX form.

Example:

```
<Dropdown label="Select Client"
name="select Client"
options={dropdownOptions}
handleClick={this.handleClick} />
```

In Dropdown:

```
render() {
    return(
        <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>Click me</button>
    )
}
```

When you pass down handleClick, ALWAYS BIND IT. Side-note: If you find you don't need to bind the function, don't pass it down in props. Just instantiate the function in the child component to maintain a separation of concerns.

For more on handling events in React, see their documentation:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply...however in component i can see the prop as a function however it does not invoke the controller function but rather invokes component function. I want to change the state of a field in controller on selecting a option. I have seen it done in other project but somehow i am missing the gap.

Comment: I was able to do it. You just need to map it in props.